# In what order do I have to extinguish the puzzle signs in the Gargoyle Contract quest?

Tags: the-witcher-2

There are three rooms, guarded by Gargoyles, each one with a chest and four magical signs/runes you have to extinguish in the correct order. There is also a different clue in each room.

The clue in the room I'm stuck is the following

> Divertimento!
>   Coulds are like bees 
>   When bells ring

In what order do I have to extinguish the signs? I've identified the signs in the room using the books from a merchant as animal, time, art and sky.

What are the solutions to the other possible variations of this puzzle?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Gaming.stackexchange.com! It's okay to post an answer to your own question! You should do so, for better visibility if nothing else.

Comment: I've significantly rewritten this question to make it also apply to all other variations of the puzzle and to remove the misleading and wrong identification of one sign as death.

Answer (score 16):

There seem to be multiple different puzzles, and which one is finally used in a room seems to be random.

There are three rooms in total where you must extinguish the signs in the correct order. They are all underground, look for stairs leading down in the three locations marked on this map:[image]

The descriptions of the signs are in the Books of Magical Signs Volumes 1-4, they are as following:

```
art = harp
war = clenched fist
thunder = striking lightning bolt
death = scythe
sky = line within parallelogram, pursed mouth
butterfly = line crossed twice
weather = arrow sliced in half
reason = bear dancing on dew
time = open hourglass or chalice
life = blossoming flower
animal = snake creeping along riverbead
fate = cross within circle
```

I've only had 4 different runes in my game, I identified them as the following

**Animal**

```
  __
   /
/ / /
 /
 --
```

**Time**

```
\  /
 \/
 /\
/  \
----
```

**Sky**

```
----
|\ |
| \|
----
```

**Art**

```
-----
|   /
|--/
| /
|/
```

The clues in each room are numbered, there appear to be at least 6 different ones.

**First encrypted rune combination:**

> A doe's shadow
>   The moon quietly moans 
>   It is autumm already

Solution:
animal sky art time

**Second encrypted rune combination:**

> Three field mice
>   Dance in a circle at dusk
>   Stars are like grain

Solution:
animal art time sky

**Third encrypted rune combination:**

> Glittering fish 
>   Dying on a fresco
>   Struck by lightning

Solution:
animal time art sky

**Fourth encrypted rune combination:**

> Behold the comet 
>   It is like a wolf in times of scarceness 
>   An evil lullaby.

Solution: 
sky animal time art

**Fifth encrypted rune combination:**

> Divertimento!
>   Coulds are like bees 
>   When bells ring

Solution:
art sky animal time

**Sixth encrypted rune combination:**

> On the dark sky 
>   The beauty of a falcon's flight 
>   Faster and faster

Solution:
sky art animal time

Comment: Fourth encrypted rune combination: Behold the comet \ It is like a wolf in times of scarceness \ An evil lullaby. Solution: sky animal time art.

Comment: @Simon Thanks for the last combination, finally we have all solutions here.

Comment: Does anyone else find this puzzle kind of annoyingly misleading?  When you read the Runes of Power books, it makes it sound as though you're looking for symbols beyond the four in this answer.  So I kept looking for symbols that resemble a scythe and a lightning bolt for the "Third encrypted rune combination" before finding out they don't even exist.

Answer (score 3):

About the amphitheater:
Let's assume we don't have a solution. How do we solve the puzzle?

**Clouds** are like **bees**: this one is pretty obvious: sky and animal.

**When** bells ring: more or less obvious, since when = time, but could also be a reference to "For whom the bell tolls", ergo, *death*. Still a bit of a long shot.

**Divertimento!** is haunting me, though.
It means "fun" in italian, and it also is a musical genre, generally composed for a small ensemble, this also is a light-hearted, good-mood music, also far away from the notion of death.

So I moved on and did a bit of letter swapping and realized "Divertimento" contains the letters of the word **Morte** in italian, meaning death. That is the best I could get so far.

Also, Mozart wrote his **divertimento** (K. 522, "The Musical Joke") 8 days after the *death* of his muse bird, Baptista. This one is really funny.

---

Since Fabian stated that Divertimento does not mean death, I need to correct my efforts in that direction and stay with art (music).

Answer (score 0):

I used numbers, and trial and error.

```
|----3-------------------------------4----|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|--2------------[chest]------------------1--- [entrance]
```

If you can understand this diagram, the sequence is **3, 2, 1, 4**.

Enter the room, first on your left, second straight ahead, third opposite side of second, and fourth is on the entrance side of the third.

Comment: Welcome to the site, wowzers. :) Instead of asking your question here as part of your answer, [ask a question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) through the site. That's what it's there for, after all.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see you already did that, haha.