# In the Gargoyle Contract quest, where on the roof is the third rune located?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I have 2/3 seals broken. But i can't for the life of me figure out the seal on the roof of the house. I can't find the runes anywhere and i tried doing something with the candles, but no actions are available.....

Where are the runes on the roof???

Comment: I've got the same problem, so I wandered around and got in phillipa eihart house, and I was so surprised to see it was on the rooftop, but only with candles and no action could be made :(

Comment: The puzzles are partly randomized, so we have to guess wich one you have, you'll find 4 different solutions already [in this other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/the-witcher-2-gargoyle-contract-what-is-the-ordering-of-the-signs-in-the-rooms).

Answer (score 3):

You're in the wrong place, all the seals are in underground rooms, see this map for the locations. As for the solution of the puzzle itself, take a look [at this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22784/gargoyle-contract-solution-to-the-sign-order-puzzle).

[image]